# How to fix to getting automatic flip on hover?

Tags: html, css, flip

I think something is not letting me get flip on hovering over the card.

I have tried .card:hover .front:hover and so many other but it is not working. Sorry been awake for 3 days cant wrap it, and i have the project due in couple of hours. it must be something i have been missing, if i could get some help id appreciate it

```
   <div class="card">
        <input type="checkbox" id="card" class="more">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="front" style="background-image: url()">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h2></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="info">
                        <span>1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <span>2</span>
                    <div class="info">
                        <span>3</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem unde?</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="type">Card</div>
                    <div class="button">
                        <a href='https://www.google.com/'><button>Link To Google</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 280px;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.card:hover {
  transition: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card .content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0, 0.85, 1);
}


.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.front .inner,
.back .inner {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  padding: 1.5em;
  transform: translateZ(80px) scale(0.94);
}

.front {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.front:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, rgba(67, 138, 243, 0.7), rgba(255, 242, 166, 0.7));
}
.front .inner {
  grid-template-rows: 5fr 1fr 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}
.front h2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.back .inner {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 14fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-column-gap: 0.8em;
  justify-items: center;
}
.back .info {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #355cc9;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.back .info:not(:first-of-type):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.9em;
  height: 18px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.back .info span {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.back .info i {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.back .info i:before {
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, #355cc9, #438af3);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
.back .info .icon {
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}
.back .info .icon span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -0.25em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 600;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.back .description {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  font-size: 0.70em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #355cc9;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.back .button {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  justify-self: center;
}

.button {
  grid-row: -1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2.0em;
  min-width: 3em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #355cc9;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #859ddf;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #355cc9;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fixes are:

you're using card as ID in HTML but in css it was used as `class`. I have changed HTML to `class="card"`.

Moreover, rotateY(180deg) works with [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateY) property.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 280px;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

.card:hover {
transition: width 2s, height 4s;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card .content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0, 0.85, 1);
}


.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.front .inner,
.back .inner {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  padding: 1.5em;
  transform: translateZ(80px) scale(0.94);
}

.front {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.front:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, rgba(67, 138, 243, 0.7), rgba(255, 242, 166, 0.7));
}
.front .inner {
  grid-template-rows: 5fr 1fr 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}
.front h2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.back .inner {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 14fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-column-gap: 0.8em;
  justify-items: center;
}
.back .info {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #355cc9;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.back .info:not(:first-of-type):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.9em;
  height: 18px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.back .info span {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.back .info i {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.back .info i:before {
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, #355cc9, #438af3);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
.back .info .icon {
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}
.back .info .icon span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -0.25em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 600;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.back .description {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  font-size: 0.70em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #355cc9;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.back .button {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  justify-self: center;
}

.button {
  grid-row: -1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2.0em;
  min-width: 3em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #355cc9;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #859ddf;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #355cc9;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
        <input type="checkbox" class="card" class="more">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="front">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h2>Hello</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="info">
                        <span>1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <span>2</span>
                    <div class="info">
                        <span>3</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem unde?</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="type">Card</div>
                    <div class="button">
                        <a href='https://www.google.com/'><button>Link To Google</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps!